# Raspberry Pi Online Simulator?

Tags: node.js, azure, raspberry-pi

So I am working on Microsoft Azure to create a smart parking system( basically to count number of vehicle going in and out of parking lot using the sensor data). I created a IoT hub on azure and connected the device key with Raspberry Pi online simulator. The default sample code is of a weather sensor and I want to change it and code for parking sensor, like to count number of vehicles in and out. I am confused as to how to start coding and make changes in the Raspberry Pi online simulator coding area. It uses node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the following to get it configured,

[Connect Raspberry Pi online simulator to Azure IoT Hub (Node.js)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-web-simulator-get-started)

and code samples can be found  **[`here`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-node-raspberrypi-client-app)**

Comment: Ya but that just helps with the connection part (for connecting IoT hub to it). Nothing is given about how to code.